# C# variable names with special character

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to include some special characters in a `string` variable name in C#.

**Example:**
`string foo-bar = String.Empty;`

As far as my understand I can't declare a variable as I mentioned in the above example.
Is there any way around to declare a variable name with "-" included?

Comment: Why do you need to include "-"? Interested to hear the reason.

Comment: Do you need this for serialization? Use attributes. Is it for an HTML attribute in MVC? Use underscores. Explain why you need this.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am trying to develop **sass** like css3 precompiler using c#. 
Many of the css attribute names include "-". So,
I am declaring all the css attributes as properties which is involving "-". When i covert the .cs file to .css using reflections or Expression Tree, i will get exact css attribute names from the properties.

Comment: @kranthiv I think your problem asks for a Dictionary type.

Answer (score 11):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615485%28v=vs.88%29.aspx):

> You can't just choose any sequence of characters as a variable name. This isn't as worrying as it might sound, however, because you're still left with a very flexible naming 
>   system.
>   The basic variable naming rules are as follows:
>
> The first character of a variable name must be either a letter, an underscore character (_), or the at symbol (@).
>   Subsequent characters may be letters, underscore characters, or numbers.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible to do in C#.

---

If you **really, really, really** want to so this, you could use a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> someVars = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                      {
                                          {"foo-bar", String.Empty},
                                          {"bar-foo", "bazinga"}
                                      }
```

Using them would look like this:

```
string newstring = someVars["foo-bar"] + "Hello World!";
```

Instead of just using the variable name, you would look up the string in your dictionary. Note that this is very inefficient and just intended as a joke, so please don't actually use this ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to deserialize object, you can use JsonProperty to acieve this.

Example:

```
public class SubscriptionListJsonData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "subscriptions")]
    public string SubscriptionData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@nextLink")]
    public string nextLink { get; set; }
}
```

[Follow this link for partially reading Json.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in c# and most of other programming languages .. I also advice you to follow the C# naming conventions as it help you read your code in a way that -at least for me- always felt comfortable .

Comment: F# is nice and flexible with variable naming, even permits spaces, there's a kind of quotes/brackets that is used.